# ForEach "=>" Javascript lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, controller

I want to add an if condition before I can fill the map "mapDataCible". Is that possible?

```
 inp.forEach(input => mapDataCible[input.get('v.name')] = input.get('v.value'));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard approach would be to use `.filter()`

```
inp.filter(input => input.get('v.whatever') === expected).forEach(input => mapDataCible[input.get('v.name')] = input.get('v.value'));
```

Have a read of the MDN docs on array methods:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array